# Apple mach-o linker flag error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add TapJoy in my app, after adding the TapJoy class I got this error:

```
Ld /Users/tamannarahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tapjoy-fkglfvxrrgqjzvgmabanjaqvquov/Build/Intermediates/Tapjoy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tapjoy.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Tapjoy normal armv6
    cd /Tamanna/Tapjoy
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.0
    setenv PATH "/Xcode 4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode 4/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    "/Xcode 4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2" -arch armv6 -isysroot "/Xcode 4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk" -L/Users/tamannarahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tapjoy-fkglfvxrrgqjzvgmabanjaqvquov/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/tamannarahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tapjoy-fkglfvxrrgqjzvgmabanjaqvquov/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/tamannarahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tapjoy-fkglfvxrrgqjzvgmabanjaqvquov/Build/Intermediates/Tapjoy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tapjoy.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Tapjoy.LinkFileList -dead_strip libxml2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -framework CoreTelephony -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/tamannarahman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tapjoy-fkglfvxrrgqjzvgmabanjaqvquov/Build/Intermediates/Tapjoy.build/Debug-iphoneos/Tapjoy.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Tapjoy

arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: libxml2: No such file or directory
Command /Xcode 4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of that log is:

```
libxml2: No such file or directory
```

You will want to add the libxml2 library to your project's "Link Binary with Libraries" Build Phase. I believe it's named libxml2.dylib, there may be multiple versions differing in version number.

If the library is already added, remove it and re-add it. It may be linked to the wrong Xcode installation, or the particular version may have been removed or renamed in the latest Xcode.